# slow querying in Hasura

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I am using hasura and it seems to work really slow...Even if I just run a SELECT with no WHERE or no kind of sorting, it takes too much time compared to for example using Django. My dataset is really slow (only 3 rows) and it still takes much time.

The query:

```
query MyQuery {

  youthjob_tags{name}

}
```

This is the analysis of the query:

```
Aggregate  (cost=19.52..19.52 rows=1 width=32)
  ->  Seq Scan on tags  (cost=0.00..14.08 rows=1360 width=32)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=32)
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(json_agg("root"), '[]') AS "root"
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      row_to_json(
        (
          SELECT
            "_1_e"
          FROM
            (
              SELECT
                "_0_root.base"."name" AS "name"
            ) AS "_1_e"
        )
      ) AS "root"
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          "youthjob"."tags"
        WHERE
          ('true')
      ) AS "_0_root.base"
  ) AS "_2_root"
```

Comment: what do you mean by slow ? this is a very small query, it should be very fast, you might have another problem.

Comment: Fetching the data from a frontend and using igraphql both take up to 1-2 seconds. I was just wondering if anyone could see any potential redflags in the information I sent, for example if the generated sql looks bad

Comment: Where is the database located that you're communicating with? There is nothing wrong with the query plan or the generated SQL here

Comment: I use the free plan on Hasura which means it is in California while I am in Sweden. But should that really make it that slow?

Answer (score 3):

If Hasura is running in California and you are in Sweden and your database is in Sweden then the network traffic would look like this:

1. You send GQL Request to Hasura: Sweden -> California
2. Hasura sends SQL statement to Database: California -> Sweden
3. Database sends response to Hasura: Sweden -> California
4. Hasura sends response back to you: California -> Sweden

According to [these ping times](https://wondernetwork.com/pings/Stockholm) each hop is across `8844km` with a minimum latency of `160ms` so I'd be expecting around 1 full second of pure network latency without even considering the actual processing time of each service

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I think that the database I am using is in California (I created it within Hasura and I think they are using databases in California). That is why I still think the time is little weird. But in the coming days I will buy Hasura in London and see if it speeds up the responsetime.

Comment: @odinhufnagl What database did you connect to your Hasura instance? Did you use the free Heroku option?

Comment: Yep, I used the free option which is Heroku